# How can I rewrite this nested callback hell functions with the async await/promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, callback

I am new to `Nodejs`. I have to perform some set of functions one after one since the tasks are dependent on each other. So I thought to use the callback functon way where I am calling another `callback` means `nested callbacks` one after other in order to achieve the results.

But then after somewhere I came to know about the `Callback Hells` and that should be avoided. So then I am now confused then how to use `promises/ async-await` to achieve that?

And also how its different than the nested callbacks since in promises also then next prmise is called only when the first promise is resolved hence it has too the nested callback nature.

Please someone can correct me what I am doing wrong?

```
    router.route('/addTasks-approve').get(function(req, res) {
    
if(req.query.text == 'Approved')
                     {
                      User.updateMany({'Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},
                         {$set: {"Addtasks.$.width" :'250px',
                          "Addtasks.$.height" :'32px',
                          "Addtasks.$.background" :'linear-gradient(45deg, #0f3443, #34e89e)',
                          "Addtasks.$.border_radius" :'10px / 5px',
                         "Addtasks.$.status" :req.query.text}},
                        function (error, success) {
                              if (!error) {
                                console.log("Approved color set!");
                                User.findOne({tag:'Admin','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},function (error, dataAdmin) {
                                      if (error) {
                                          console.log("error = "+ error);
                                          res.end('{"msg" : "Some error occurred", "status" : 700}');
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        dataAdmin.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
                                          if(element.commonID == req.query.id)
                                          {
                                     User.findOneAndUpdate({tag:'Client','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},
                                     {$push: {'Addtasks.$.Bigpaths4Clients':{$each : element.Bigpaths4Clients}},
                                      $set: {"Addtasks.$.background" :'linear-gradient(45deg, #1E6305, #BDFF00)',
                                             "Addtasks.$.status" :'Done'}},
                                        function (error, data) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                console.log("error = "+ error);
                                                res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to add the Task", "status" : 700}');
                                              }
                                              else {
                                                console.log("Addtasks added to Client's dashboard succesfully");
                                                sendMails2Client(data.email, element.topic, 'In Progress', 'Done');
                                                sendMails2User(dataAdmin.email, element.topic, 'Done', 'Approved');
                                                User.findOne({tag:'Admin','Addtasks.commonID':req.query.id},function (error, dataWriter) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          console.log("error = "+ error);
                                                          res.end('{"msg" : "Some error occurred", "status" : 700}');
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                        sendMails2User(dataWriter.email, element.topic, 'Done', 'Approved');
                                                        res.end('{"success" : "success", "status" : 200}');
                                                      }
                                                    })
                                              }
                                      })
                                    }
                                  });
                                }
                              });
                              }
                              else {
                                res.end('{"msg" : "Unable to set the status and color for Approved", "status" : 700}');
                              }
                            });
                          }                 
})
```

Comment: Is the `element.commonID == req.query.id` test designed to match one element or (potentially) more than one element?

Comment: one element only. why? Should I use the find() then? Please let me know. @Roamer-1888

Comment: What you are doing is effectively `dataAdmin.Addtasks.filter(...).forEach(...)`. If the filter is intended to pick out a single element then the rest of the code will be simpler than if it picks out multiple elements.

Comment: should I replace all the foreach with filter? Is that you are saying? @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this [article](https://medium.com/@ashokjayaprakash/callback-vs-promise-vs-async-await-6c4081f0f0d3), it's about Callback vs Promise vs async/await with example...
but I prefer `asyn/await`

your code base on `asyn/await`:

```
router.route("/addTasks-approve").get(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.query.text == "Approved") {
      try {
        let resUpdate = await User.updateMany(
            { "Addtasks.commonID": req.query.id },
            {
              $set: {
                "Addtasks.$.width": "250px",
                "Addtasks.$.height": "32px",
                "Addtasks.$.background": "linear-gradient(45deg, #0f3443, #34e89e)",
                "Addtasks.$.border_radius": "10px / 5px",
                "Addtasks.$.status": req.query.text,
              },
            }
          );
            console.log("Approved color set!");
            let dataAdmin = await User.findOne({
              tag: "Admin",
              "Addtasks.commonID": req.query.id,
            });
      
            dataAdmin.Addtasks.forEach(async (element) => {
              if (element.commonID == req.query.id) {
                let data = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                  { tag: "Client", "Addtasks.commonID": req.query.id },
                  {
                    $push: {
                      "Addtasks.$.Bigpaths4Clients": {
                        $each: element.Bigpaths4Clients,
                      },
                    },
                    $set: {
                      "Addtasks.$.background":
                        "linear-gradient(45deg, #1E6305, #BDFF00)",
                      "Addtasks.$.status": "Done",
                    },
                  }
                );
      
                console.log("Addtasks added to Client's dashboard succesfully");
                await sendMails2Client(data.email,element.topic,"In Progress","Done");
                await sendMails2User(dataAdmin.email,element.topic,"Done","Approved");
                let dataWriter = await User.findOne({
                  tag: "Admin",
                  "Addtasks.commonID": req.query.id,
                });
                await sendMails2User(dataWriter.email, element.topic, "Done", "Approved");
                res.end('{"success" : "success", "status" : 200}');
              }
            });
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
    
  }
});
```

but for error handling you should use `try/catch` for any part of your code that an error may occur

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you tell me why you used the async again with foreach loop but not the await function? @Mohammad Yaser?

Comment: actually when I need a loop in async function I use `async` module (search async npm) it's perfect you can check the documentation (https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) and `q npm` module. if you want after loop execute the other lines need to  async foreach, beacuse  findOneAndUpdate is a time consuming task

Comment: with `q` and `async` loop you can create a promise functioan and the call your own function in this function to increase the lines of code

Comment: Did you mean that i need to install the async pacage first to use this? I thought it comes all natural with nodejs.

Comment: for using `async.each()` or using `async.eachSeries()` you nead to install the package, but they are like array.forEach(async(el)=>{}), don't worry about thisو With review samples , little by little, you will all understand

Comment: so whatever you have used the async keyword in my code will work without installing the async package?

Comment: for using `async.each()` you nead to the async module check it https://www.npmjs.com/package/async, async keyword is a javascript's keyword

Comment: yes, But I am saying that you havnet used async with each in my code so i dont need that package.

Comment: i dont understand this line:

 if you want after loop execute the other lines need to async foreach, beacuse findOneAndUpdate is a time consuming task –

Comment: when you use async for a consuming task, other line after that don't executed until last task Done

Comment: Lastly can you tell me why nested callbacks should be avoided? Since frankly telling I am unable to distinguish it with async/await or promises. Becauss with async/await also the the next task is executed only after the above await task not get completed and hence it happens with callbacks also.

Comment: In JavaScript, we have a few different ways to handle asynchronicity: callback functions, Promises, and async-await, **All three do the same thing**, but `async/await` 1- The syntax is cleaner. There are fewer brackets and less to get wrong. 2- Debugging is easier. Breakpoints can be set on any await statement 3- Error handling is better. try/catch blocks can be used in the same way as synchronous code 4-Support is good. It’s implemented in all browsers (except IE and Opera Mini) and Node 7.6+

Comment: read this article please https://dev.to/nas5w/asynchronous-javascript-how-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-work-1f7p

Comment: if my answers were useful, please upvote my answer, take care bro

Comment: Also why you have not used the try catch for each awat function? Is only one try catch required for whole end point? Means what if in between any method catches an error?

Comment: If you want when a error occur, But the next function be done, you should use try catch for each function, but But I thought that when an error occurred, the next lines did not need to be done, Everything depends on you